# Using WebView webView:didCommitLoadForFrame

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webkit, webview

Im fairly new to Xcode, so please bear with me. I have a small porject, and made a class that looks like this:

**webController.m**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "WebKit/WebView.h"
#import "WebKit/WebFrame.h"

@class WebView;

@interface webController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet WebView *lyricWebView;

}
- (IBAction)loadWebPage:(id)sender;
@end
```

**webController.h**

```
- (IBAction)loadWebPage:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"loading the page...");

    NSString *webpage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://somepage.com"];

    [lyricWebView setMainFrameURL:webpage]; 

}
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didCommitLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    NSLog(@"This is the problem...");
}
```

I have `loadWebPage` linked to a button, but I need to inject some scripts to the wepage using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`, which I need to run after the page has finished loading. I know I need to use `webView:didComitLoadForFrame`, but havent yet found out how or where to implement it so it will run when the frame is loaded. I've been looking arround all day... and decided finally to ask. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I just needed to set the delegate :D

Comment: For anyone who may need it, you can set it with `[WebView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];`. I have this line of code on my `-(void)awakeFromNib`.